# What is the probability that at least one out of three systems will work if the probability of one failing is 0.2, the second failing is 0.1?

Tags: probability, statistics

I have a probability question that is part of a Master's programme. The scenario is:

The probability that a factory’s sprinkler system will fail is 0.2; the probability that its alarm system will fail is 0.1; the probability that both will fail simultaneously is 0.04. What is the probability that at least one will work?

My thinking is to calculate P(Sprinkler system not failing) + P(Alarm system not failing) + P(Not both failing simultaneously) = 0.8 + 0.1 + 0.96, but that gives a probability greater than 1 which is not possible.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the probability that at least one system will work is the complement of the probability that both fail simultaneously, thus the result is $1-0.04=0.96$

you can see the solution using Venn's diagrams

Comment: Thank you! Would the Venn diagram look like an intersection between two events?